# Xperia xa2 restart loop

Tags: reboot, sony-xperia

I have purchased Sony Xperia XA2 from UK. Initially had this problem of the phone in restart loop mode when I memory is more than 95%.for this once it gets started I immediately delete all large files.
Now since yesterday the phone is not moving past the Xperia logo ,it keeps restarting. 
Sony service center advised that cannot touch the phone as this was purchased in UK so can't repair it in India.
Anyone here can you please help me to fix this issue. I have 1000s of kids photos and videos I can't lose it as I didn't back up it.
Thanks much in advance.